# How to retrieve a layer in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Given a `caffe.Net` object, what's the best way to access a particular layer?
Right now I only figured how to iterate over them, which is not very useful:

```
for i in range(n_layers):
  print net.layers[i].type
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish by "accessing a particular layer"?

Comment: Debugging. Just want to inspect some of the member variables of the layers.

Comment: in that case, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can get all the layers' names by

```
all_names = [n for n in net._layer_names]
```

of course if you want to inspect the values of the learned parameters, you can see how it's done in this [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) example.

For instance, if you want to inspect the filters of `conv1` layer (assuming you have a layer with that name in your model) you can access

```
In [1]: net.params['conv1'][0].data.shape
Out[1]: (64, 3, 3, 3)
```

And the bias term of this layer

```
In [2]: net.params['conv1'][1].data.shape
Out[2]: (64,)
```

As you can see, this is the first layer of an image processing net, it has 64 filters acting on 3x3 patches of BGR (3 channels) input.

If you already fed data through the net (using `net.forward`, or `net.backward`) you can inspect the responses of the different layers to the specific inputs fed through the net:

```
In [3]: net.blobs['conv1'].data.shape
Out[3]: (1, 64, 198, 198)
```

The output shape of `conv1` layer is 198x198 pixels with 64 channels (there are 64 filters in this layer) and the batch size is 1.
If you performed a backward pass as well, you can also inspect the gradients computed at this layer:

```
In [4]: net.blobs['conv1'].diff.shape
Out[4]: (1, 64, 198, 198)
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort, but I clearly asked how to get a hold of layers objects not blobs. E.g. I want to access some internal data unexposed to blobs.

Comment: @memecs what internal data? the layer's parameters? you'll have to be more specific. Please update your question accordingly, do you'll get better answers

Comment: @Shai I have a model that uses Flatten layers. This layer is in `net._layer_names` but it can't be found in net.params. How would I access the shape of that Flatten layer?

Comment: @Anton"Flatten" layer is a "parameter-free" layer and therefore it has no `net.params`. On the other hand, you can check its input and output blob shapes via `net.blobs`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use case:**

I need to set the running mean and var in batchnorm layer, which is not in `net.params` or `net.blobs`

**Solution:**

`net.layer_dict['bn_layer_name'].blobs[0].data` is running mean. `blobs[1]` is var. `blobs[2]` set to 1, it's a scale that defaults to 0.
[image]

**How do I find it:**

`print(net.__dir__())` and then guess and try.