# Net surgery: How to reshape a convolution layer of a caffemodel file in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to reshape the size of a convolution layer of a caffemodel (This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847270/net-surgery-on-a-custom-caffe-model)). Although there is a tutorial on [how to do net surgery](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb), it only shows how to copy weight parameters from one caffemodel to another of the same size.
Instead I need to add a new channel (all 0) to my convolution filter such that it changes its size from currently (`64`x`3`x`3`x`3`) to (`64`x`4`x`3`x`3`).

Say the convolution layer is called `'conv1'`. This is what I tried so far:

```
# Load the original network and extract the fully connected layers' parameters.
net = caffe.Net('../models/train.prototxt', 
                '../models/train.caffemodel', 
                caffe.TRAIN)
```

Now I can perform this:

```
net.blobs['conv1'].reshape(64,4,3,3);
net.save('myNewTrainModel.caffemodel');
```

But the saved model seems not to have changed. I've read that the actual weights of the convolution are stored rather in `net.params['conv1'][0].data` than in `net.blobs` but I can't figure out how to reshape the `net.params` object. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you well noted, `net.blobs` does not store the learned parameters/weights, but rather stores the result of applying the filters/activations on the net's input. The learned weights are stored in `net.params`. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265993/1714410) for more details).

AFAIK, you cannot directly `reshape` `net.params` and add a channel.
What you can do, is have two nets `deploy_trained_net_with_3ch.prototxt` and `deploy_empty_net_with_4ch.prototxt`. The two files can be almost identical apart from the input shape definition and the first layer's name.
Then you can load **both** nets to python and copy the relevant part:

```
net3ch = caffe.Net('deploy_trained_net_with_3ch.prototxt', 'train.caffemodel', caffe.TEST) 
net4ch = caffe.Net('deploy_empty_net_with_4ch.prototxt', 'train.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
```

since all layer names are identical (apart from `conv1`) `net4ch.params` will have the weights of `train.caffemodel`. As for the first layer, you can now manually copy the relevant part:

```
net4ch.params['conv1_4ch'][0].data[:,:3,:,:] = net3ch.params['conv1'][0].data[...]
```

and finally:

```
net4ch.save('myNewTrainModel.caffemodel')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so many questions. You really helped me a lot! Might still have some questions in the future though ;)