# How to reduce a fully-connected (`"InnerProduct"`) layer using truncated SVD

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-algebra, deep-learning, caffe

In the paper [*Girshick, R* **Fast-RCNN** (ICCV 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08083), section "3.1 Truncated SVD for faster detection", the author proposes to use [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) trick to reduce the size and computation time of a fully connected layer.

Given a *trained* model (`deploy.prototxt` and `weights.caffemodel`), how can I use this trick to replace a fully connected layer with a truncated one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Some linear-algebra background**
Singular Value Decomposition ([SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) is a decomposition of any matrix `W` into three matrices:

```
W = U S V*
```

Where `U` and `V` are ortho-normal matrices, and `S` is diagonal with elements in decreasing magnitude on the diagonal. 
One of the interesting properties of SVD is that it allows to easily approximate `W` with a lower rank matrix: Suppose you truncate `S` to have only its `k` leading elements (instead of all elements on the diagonal) then

```
W_app = U S_trunc V*
```

is a rank `k` approximation of `W`.

**Using SVD to approximate a fully connected layer**
Suppose we have a model `deploy_full.prototxt` with a fully connected layer

```
# ... some layers here
layer {
  name: "fc_orig"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "in"
  top: "out"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1000
    # more params...
  }
  # some more...
}
# more layers...
```

Furthermore, we have `trained_weights_full.caffemodel` - trained parameters for `deploy_full.prototxt` model.

1. Copy `deploy_full.protoxt` to `deploy_svd.protoxt` and open it in editor of your choice. *Replace* the fully connected layer with these two layers:

   ```
   layer {
     name: "fc_svd_U"
     type: "InnerProduct"
     bottom: "in" # same input
     top: "svd_interim"
     inner_product_param {
       num_output: 20  # approximate with k = 20 rank matrix
       bias_term: false
       # more params...
     }
     # some more...
   }
   # NO activation layer here!
   layer {
     name: "fc_svd_V"
     type: "InnerProduct"
     bottom: "svd_interim"
     top: "out"   # same output
     inner_product_param {
       num_output: 1000  # original number of outputs
       # more params...
     }
     # some more...
   }
   ```
2. In python, a little [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb):

   ```
   import caffe
   import numpy as np

   orig_net = caffe.Net('deploy_full.prototxt', 'trained_weights_full.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
   svd_net = caffe.Net('deploy_svd.prototxt', 'trained_weights_full.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
   # get the original weight matrix
   W = np.array( orig_net.params['fc_orig'][0].data )
   # SVD decomposition
   k = 20 # same as num_ouput of fc_svd_U
   U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(W)
   S = np.zeros((U.shape[0], k), dtype='f4')
   S[:k,:k] = s[:k]  # taking only leading k singular values
   # assign weight to svd net
   svd_net.params['fc_svd_U'][0].data[...] = np.dot(U,S)
   svd_net.params['fc_svd_V'][0].data[...] = V[:k,:]
   svd_net.params['fc_svd_V'][1].data[...] = orig_net.params['fc_orig'][1].data # same bias
   # save the new weights
   svd_net.save('trained_weights_svd.caffemodel')
   ```

Now we have `deploy_svd.prototxt` with `trained_weights_svd.caffemodel` that approximate the original net with far less multiplications, and weights.

Comment: amazing solution :)

Comment: @Dale not my solution - it's Ross Girshick's.

Comment: I think you meant to write `W_app = U S_trunc V*`.

Comment: This is a nice solution, and technically correct but it's important to note when you should and should not leave the two linear layers seperate vs multiplying them together and making them one. if K isn't much smaller than either matrix dimension, then it may be fewer multiplies altogether to recombine them. (remember for matrix multiplication x(AB)=(xA)B. x(AB) might be fewer multiplies than (xA)B, if AB is precomputed, and if k isn't small enough)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Ross Girshick's py-faster-rcnn repo includes an implementation for the SVD step: [`compress_net.py`](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/compress_net.py).

BTW, you usually need to fine-tune the compressed model to recover the accuracy (or to compress in a more sophisticated way, see for example "[Accelerating Very Deep Convolutional Networks for Classification and Detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.06798)", Zhang et al).

Also, for me scipy.linalg.svd worked faster than numpy's svd.