# Conv 1x1 configuration for feature reduction

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am using 1x1 convolution in the deep network to reduce a feature **x**: `Bx2CxHxW` to `BxCxHxW`. I have three options:

1. x -> Conv (1x1) ->  Batchnorm-->ReLU. Code will be `output = ReLU(BN(Conv(x)))`. Reference [resnet](https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/blob/a7026cb6d478e131b765b898c312e25f9f6dc031/prototxt/ResNet-101-deploy.prototxt#L95)
2. x -> BN -> ReLU-> Conv. So the code will be `output = Conv(ReLU(BN(x)))` . Reference [densenet](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/038105ff3a18f42903903d2a7714f2e083932a6a/torchvision/models/densenet.py#L50)
3. x-> Conv. The code is `output = Conv(x)`

Which one is most using for feature reduction? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are going to train your net end-to-end, whatever configuration you are using - the weights will be trained to accommodate them.

**BatchNorm?**
I guess the first question you need to ask yourself is do you want to use `BatchNorm`? If your net is deep and you are concerned with [covariate shifts](http://mlexplained.com/2018/01/10/an-intuitive-explanation-of-why-batch-normalization-really-works-normalization-in-deep-learning-part-1/) then you probably should have a `BatchNorm` -- and here goes option no. 3

**BatchNorm first?**
If your `x` is the output of another `conv` layer, than there's actually no difference between your first and second alternatives: your net is a cascade of ...-`conv`-`bn`-`ReLU`-`conv`-`BN`-`ReLU`-`conv`-... so it's only an "artificial" partitioning of the net into triplets of functions `conv`, `bn`, `relu` and up to the very first and last functions you can split things however you wish. Moreover, since Batch norm is a linear operation (scale + bias) it can be "folded" into an adjacent `conv` layer without changing the net, so you basically left with `conv`-`relu` pairs.
So, there's not really a big difference between the first two options you highlighted.

**What else to consider?**
Do you really need `ReLU` when changing dimension of features? You can think of the reducing dimensions as a linear mapping - decomposing the weights mapping **to** `x` into a lower *rank* matrix that ultimately maps into `c` dimensional space instead of `2c` space. If you consider a linear mapping, then you might omit the `ReLU` altogether.
See [fast RCNN SVD trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480827/1714410) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for recommending the third way. I think I will ignore relu. So simple version will be `Conv(BN(x))` because I have checked the x that is the output of a convolution.